# Generating unique permutations from a list of big size n, while addressing the memory problem

Tags: python, memory, permutation

I am trying to find an efficient and quick way to generate an enormous set of possible permutations. Here is an examplary list from which I want to get all unique permutations. [-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,0,0,0,0].
My 12 gb ram gets full before the process gets completed. One idea is to append each generated permutation in a excel file and then delete it from the memory.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: use itertools  this is exact;y what it is there for, do yoou pllan on doing somehing with each permutation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.permutations` will yield one permutation at a time, so it solves the memory issue.

But in your sample list you only have 3 distinct values. This means that while the permutations of 20 items are around `2.43e+18` the distinct permutations you can obtain from that list are just `6.23e+07` - still a large number, but definitely more manageable. So you may want to define your own generator and yield only the distinct permutations - this will surely be much faster.